# How to repeat characters in a string in javascript by using slice function?

Tags: javascript, character, slice, repeat

Can anyone shed light on how to frame a javascript function with two parameters: string and character, and only by using the slice method, return the number of times "a" appears in "lava"?

Comment: I wonder why one would use the "slice" method to search for a character in a string, this method is not meant to do that. Moreover it's probably a bad choice for performances, and you can't do it with "only" the slice method anyway, you have to compare 'a' with each character of "lava". Rather use a good old loop.

Comment: One more remark, your title says "how to repeat a char ?", but your description says "How to count a char ?". Which question is the right one ? Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

without slice method

```js
var fruits= "lavaaagg";
var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<fruits.length;i++){
  if(fruits[i]!='a')
      count++;
 }
console.log(fruits.length-count);
```

Comment: Wow.. never knew c++ like string access was possible in JS .Great +1

Comment: @Op now you really wanted to count number of `a` using slice method ?

Comment: OP with 1 rep often vanish after posting x-)

Comment: @procrastinator yeah it's like we got some problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the slice method. The slice method isn't for searching substrings (or characters in your case), it extracts a substring.
This should work fine:

```
function howManyCharInStr(str, char) {
  return str.split(char).length - 1;
}
```

Step-by-step explanation:

```
str.split(char)
```

Creates an array of str substrings, using char as a separator. For example:

```
'fooXbazXbar'.split('X')
// Evaluates to ['foo', 'baz', 'bar']
'lorem ipsum dolor'.split('m')
// Evaluates to ['lore', ' ipsu', ' dolor']
```

Notice how the array returned has a length of *n*+1 where *n* is the number of separators there were. So use

```
str.split(char).length - 1;
```

to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

For getting number of charecters count

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function FindResults() {
        var firstvariable= document.getElementById('v1');
        var secondvariable = document.getElementById('v2');
        var rslt = GetCharecterCount(firstvariable, secondvariable );
    }
    function GetCharecterCount(var yourstring,var charecter){
          var matchesCount = yourstring.split(charecter).length - 1;
    } 
 </script>
```

using slice method

```
var arr = yourstring.split(charecter);

for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var idx = yourstring.indexOf( arr[i] );
    arr[i] = pos = (pos + idx);
    str = str.slice(idx);
}

var x= arr.length-1;
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/rWJ5x/2/

Comment: Where is the "slice" method ? :-)

Comment: A word count, why not x-)

Answer (score 0):

Using slice method

```js
function logic(str,char){
  var count = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    if(str.slice(i,i+1) == char){
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count;
};
console.log( "count : " + logic("lava","a") );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repeat last character of sting n number of times..

function modifyLast(str, n) {
    var newstr = str.slice(-1)
    var newlaststr = newstr.repeat(n-1)
    var concatstring = str.concat(newlaststr);
    return concatstring;
}
//modifyLast();
console.log(modifyLast("Hellodsdsds", 3))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).